# Migrate MODX Revo from subdomain to the main domain

Tags: modx, migrate, modx-revolution

I am stuck on a migration of a MODX revo Website from a subdomain to the root domain.

This is what I do:

1. I clear the cache of my "subdomain.mywebsite.com"
2. I logout from "subdomain.mywebsite.com"
3. I export a copy of the database using on "subdomain.mywebsite.com"
4. I zip and download all the files of "subdomain.mywebsite.com"

Now I have some questions:

1. Do I have to install a new MODX on "mywebsite.com" or simply copy the files I downloaded from "subdomain.mywebsite.com"?
2. What with the Database? Do I simply need to import it? Or there is no need because I'm on the same server?
3. Ho can I update the links? I mean from "subdomain.mywebsite.com" to "mywebsite.com"

Could you guys please explain me? Or am I doing something completely wrong?

Im new on MODX and reading [this guide](https://modx.com/blog/2015/09/21/migrating-your-modx-site/) I found I cannot go further sad

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

considerung that both domains are on the same webserver, I can describe what I am doing when shifting a website from subdomain to main domain.

- move all files from subdomain to main domain via FTP. That can happen either in the ftp client directly or with a download and upload. Moving inside the FTP client is a lot faster of course.
- edit the **config.inc.php** files inside the follofing locations to match the new folder structure: **/core/config/**, **/connectors/**, **/manager/** and in the **root** folder.
- edit the **base URL** in your template

Then: give it a try. Maybe you have to delete the files inside /core/cache/ by hand. Make youre you dont delete the /core/cache/logs/" from there.

Database should be fine as long as subdomain and domain are on the same server. The connection data to the database server will very likely be the same, regardless of the domain.

Some people run a MODX setup after they moved and edited everything to make sure everything is in place.